# API Version update from v1 to v2 in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, swift5

In my application I want to update API URL from v1 to v2

"api/myapplication/v1/get_data/"

"api/myapplication/v2/get_data/"

Directly change the url from v1 to v2.
Data printed successfully in console for v2, but page not displaying for v2 url.

[Showing something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igTWO.png)

Comment: can you check the version2 URL in postman? Does it work? maybe your backend doesn't support backward compatibility.

Comment: V2 url is working fine checked in postman, even data also printed in console.